# How to use multiple conditions, including selecting on quantile in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, select

Imagine the following dataset `df`:

| Row | Population_density | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 400 | 50 |
| 2 | 500 | 30 |
| 3 | 300 | 40 |
| 4 | 200 | 120 |
| 5 | 500 | 60 |
| 6 | 1000 | 50 |
| 7 | 3300 | 30 |
| 8 | 500 | 90 |
| 9 | 700 | 100 |
| 10 | 1000 | 110 |
| 11 | 900 | 200 |
| 12 | 850 | 30 |

How can I make a new dummy column that represents a 1 when values of `df['Population_density']` are above the third quantile (>75%) AND the `df['Distance']` is < 100, while a 0 is given to the remainder of the data? Consequently, rows 6 and 7 should have a 1 while the other rows should have a 0.

Creating a dummy variable with only one criterium can be fairly easy. For instance, the following condition works for creating a new dummy variable that contains a 1 when the Distance is <100 and a 0 otherwise: `df['Distance_Below_100'] = np.where(df['Distance'] < 100, 1, 0)`. However, I do not know how to combine conditions whereby one of the conditions includes a quantile selection (in this case, the upper 25% of the variable `Population_density`.

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Row': range(1,13,1), 'Population_density': [400, 500, 300, 200, 500, 1000, 3300, 500, 700, 1000, 900, 850],
        'Distance': [50, 30, 40, 120, 60, 50, 30, 90, 100, 110, 200, 30]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` or `|` to join the conditions

```py
import numpy as np

df['Distance_Below_100'] = np.where(df['Population_density'].gt(df['Population_density'].quantile(0.75)) & df['Distance'].lt(100), 1, 0)
```

```
print(df)

    Row  Population_density  Distance  Distance_Below_100
0     1                 400        50                   0
1     2                 500        30                   0
2     3                 300        40                   0
3     4                 200       120                   0
4     5                 500        60                   0
5     6                1000        50                   1
6     7                3300        30                   1
7     8                 500        90                   0
8     9                 700       100                   0
9    10                1000       110                   0
10   11                 900       200                   0
11   12                 850        30                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

he, to make a function on data frame i recommended to use lambda.

for example this is your function:

```
def myFunction(value):
 pass
```

to create a new column 'new_column', (pick_cell) is which cell you want to make a function on:

```
df['new_column']= df.apply(lambda x : myFunction(x.pick_cell))
```